# FB-messenger share API ignore URL parameters on Android

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, messenger

I'm using Facebook SDK (Javascript) to share a link on messenger.

I'm following the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/messenger/?locale=en_EN), like so :

```
function inviteFacebookFriends(event_id) {

  // Share on messenger
  var link = 'example.com/?event=' + event_id + '&score=' + score + '&color=' + color; // score & color are global variables
  var messenger_link = 'fb-messenger://share?link=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + '&app_id=' + encodeURIComponent(myAppId);

  window.open(messenger_link);
}
```

This function in called on click event.

While the link should be sent like this `example.com/?event=foobar123&score=5&color=red`, **all parameters are being ignored** when shared with some device (URL arrived on messenger like this : `example.com/`). Whereas it's working perfectly fine with some other devices.

Last bug reported on Android (7.1.1) using Chrome (61.0.3163.98).

## What I tried (and didn't work)

- Putting the link into an `href` to check if the problem was caused by `window.open`
- Replace single quotes by double quotes
- Hard-coded a working encoded link :

  ```
  window.open("fb-messenger://share?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%3Fevent%3Da123umw00m%26app_id%XXXXXX%26color%3Dblue%26score%123")
  ```

Still working on some device, and not on some others : sharing links ignore URL parameters.

Comment: same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: I reported the issue to Facebook dev team, they « assigned it » but I never had any news about it.